# Problem with Illustrator Pattern brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Can someone tell me if there is a way to stop my pattern brush to stop bunching up if I make a cut in my line? Or is it just something it does, and there is no way to fix it?

Preferably, I would like to be able to draw a line with my brush, cut it, and not have to outline it, just to keep the shape of the pattern

[image: Here is how it bunches up when I cut the line]

Comment: Have you tried merely adjusting the `Fit` options in the Brush Options dialog?

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't stop it form bunching together unfortunatly

Comment: To be honest, I'm really not seeing an issue if `Approximate Path` is selected in the Brush Settings.... [SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvLry.png) -- Realize if you are seeking *exact precision* of the squares, then brushes may not work. Brushes are *not* about precise sizing of the artwork.

Comment: Well, I'll try setting git to approcimate path and see if it word any better - but thanks anyway!

Comment: Note that if you are using the built in *automatic* corner generation, things get really weird (even on straight segments). If you need corners, you need to manually create the corners and *not* allow Illustrator to generate the corner artwork.